# Ignore a java bean field while converting into JSON Only if it's value hasn't been set

Tags: java, json, javabeans, pojo

I have class ABCResponse and isActive is a member of the class. While converting the ABCResponse to JSON i wanna ignore the isActive field only if it's value hasn't been set explicitly. (isActive is boolean and i know by default its value will be false, but any possible way to ignore this if its value hasn't set explicitly?)

I can't use @JSONIgnore, coz it will ignore even it's value has been set.

public class ABCResponse {

```
private boolean isActive;
private int id;

@JsonProperty("isActive")
public boolean isActive() {
    return isActive;
}
public void setActive(boolean isActive) {
    this.isActive = isActive;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to the wrapper type `Boolean` so that it can be null, and use the following annotation at a class level: `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` or `@JsonInclude(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)` if you are using version 2.x+ of Jackson

Comment: Can you please upvote and accept my answer then? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First use isActive as Boolean, so that its default value could null.

use annotation at top of the class:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) // in jackson 2.x

in earlier version use:

@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.ALWAYS)
```

an alternate configuration could be:

```
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL); // in jackson 2.x

in earlier versions use:

mapper.getSerializationConfig().setSerializationInclusion(Inclusion.NON_NULL);
```